# bootstrap 3 change position carousel-indicators

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with the carousel-indicators.
How can I change the position of the carousel-indicators to the left?

Please see more at: http://adivi.andweb.de

thx
Uli

Comment: Please give us some more Information about your Problem. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply following styles to .carousel:

```
.carousel: {
margin-top: 77px;
height: 100%;
margin-bottom: 0px;
max-width: 1170px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
}
```

And change the indicators' styles:

```
.carousel-indicators {
position: absolute;
bottom: 10px;
left: 0;
z-index: 15;
width: 60%;
margin-left: 20px;
list-style: none;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work - the position of the carousel-indicators will change, when the window-size change. :(

Comment: thx Nazar, in the meantime I found another solution that works. I placed a container around the slider and change something in the indicators' style.

Comment: That's another solution but my one is a bit easier :). Good luck!

Comment: In the code above, I believe text-align should be left if you want it left. You will then change paddings and margins as needed.